# SQLBULKCOPY.WriteToServer() does not throw an error, but it doesn't write back to the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlbulkcopy

`SQLBULKCOPY.WriteToServer()` does not throw an error, but it doesn't write back to the DB

**My current attempt**

```
System.Data.DataTable tableMain = ConvertListToDataTableMain(transactionCrossCheck);
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString()))
{

   //count = tableMain.Rows.Count;
   SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
   con.Open();
   bulk.BatchSize = 10000;

   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(5, 5);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 6);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(7, 7);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(8, 8);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(9, 9);
   bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(10, 10);

   bulk.DestinationTableName = "TransactionCrossCheck";
   bulk.WriteToServer(tableMain);
   // bulk.WriteToServerAsync(tableMain);
   bulk.Close();
   con.Close();

}
```

Comment: Are you checking the right database?

Comment: This *should* work just fine; have you checked how many rows are in `tableMain` ? Have you checked you're looking *in the right database* (it is alarmingly easy to confuse them) or schema (`dbo.TransactionCrossCheck` vs `Harshith.TransactionCrossCheck`, for example). How about adding a `select count(*) from TransactionCrossCheck` *in the C# code* before and after, via `con`, to check? As a side note: "FastMember" allows you to treat a list (or any `IEnumerable<T>`) as an `IDataReader` for the purposes of `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: Yes, I am checking.  There is only one database currently. The data comes properly in the table format(tableMain) similar to the database table.

Comment: again, this should *just work*; very hard for us to help you debug it without a repro; I could put together a console exe here that created a table and filled it, but I know it would *just work*